# How to translate values from database to javascript

Tags: javascript, html, translation

I have a code that gets status values from a database. And I need to translate it into German.
How can I get the values ​​and give each one its own translation?

```
mi("span", { class: f(["fs_badge", "fs_badge_" + o.ticket.status]) }, y(o.ticket.status), 3),
```

Comment: Your question seems too vague. But there are multiple internationalization libraries you can use. You can create a function which receives a locale and a key and returns a string accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to just change the values.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll('span.fs_badge');
    
    
    elements.forEach((element) => {
      element.textContent = element.textContent.replace('closed', 'closs'),
      element.textContent = element.textContent.replace('active', 'activvv'),
      element.textContent = element.textContent.replace('new', 'newww');
    });
    }, 1000);
});
```